# How to use create event on a jQuery dialog in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, hidden-field, jquery-dialog

I've have following dialog pop-up HTML which is hidden initially when page loads(look line `style="display:none;"` in `div`):

```
<div id="searchPopContent" class="c-popup" style="display:none;">
      <div id="pop-up">
      <div class="error_msg" id="report_error" style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <form name="question_issue_form" id="question_issue_form" class="login_box" method="post" action="question_issue.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="post_url" id="post_url" value="question_issue.php"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="question_issue"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id"/>

          <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
            <tbody>    
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question is wrong" id ="chkQueWrong">Question is wrong</input>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Answers are wrong" id ="chkAnsWrong">Answers are wrong</input></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question direction is incorrect" id ="chkDirIncorrect">Question direction is incorrecct</input></td>             
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Other" id ="chkOther">Other</input></td>          
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="set_message" style="display:none;"><textarea name="que_issue_comment" id = "que_issue_comment" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>      
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="report_question_issue" class="buttonin"/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to dynamically set the value of input type hidden having id="question_id". After doing so much research I came to know that I have to use create() method of jQUery UI dialog plugin to set the hidden field value in UI dialog dynamically. I tried to call create() event in jquery dialog call but couldn't be able to set the value. Can anyone please help me in this regard please? Following is the code I tried to use create() event.

```
$(document).on("click","a[class='que_issue']", function (e) {
var hypertext = this.innerHTML;
  var que_id = hypertext.substring(3);

  //document.getElementById("question_id").value = que_id;
  //$("#question_id").val(str);

    var data = $('#searchPopContent').html();

    var title = "Question issue";
    var dialog_title   = title; 
    var dialog_message = data; 
            var $dialog = $("<div class='view_result'></div>")
     .html(dialog_message)
     .dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           modal:true,
           title: dialog_title,
           width: 400,                     
           close:{
           },
           create: function() {
       $("#question_id").val(que_id);
    }
     });
     $dialog.dialog('open');

    return false;
});
```

Also there is no errror in the firebug console for above code.

Comment: I didn't read your question yet, but have you tried to change your click event to `$(document).on("click","a.que_issue",` ?

Comment: @Pavlo:Yes I tried with this also but my issue is not regading calling and displaying the dialog. My issue is setting the value of hidden field present on a dialog using create event.

Comment: Can you show it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you try it in open event: `open: function() { $("#question_id").val(que_id); }` just like `create` http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Comment: @user3280126:I tried with it but got some error. May be I'd written code at wrong place. I'm not understanding where should I wrie those events in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your JS: http://jsfiddle.net/JyPLc/1/ , it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#searchPopContent").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal:true,
       title: "Question issue",
       width: 400, 
       close:{
       }   
     });
});

$("a.que_issue").on("click", function (e) {
    var hypertext = this.innerHTML;
    var que_id = hypertext.substring(3);
    var title = "Question issue";

    $("#question_id").val(que_id);
    $("#qns_id").val(que_id); //this is just to show it works, can delete it
    $("#searchPopContent").dialog('open');

    return false;
});
```

You should modify the HTML first, then just call the dialog() to show to popup.

Comment: This is not working in my scnario. As the jQUery plugin prevent s the dialog HTML elements from going into DOM I can't set the value without using create event of jQuery dialog. Youer idea works in normal scenario but not with jQuery dialog which I'm using. Can you suggest the way to implement create event in my code? Thanks for your try.

Comment: It's working in fiddle. Let me check with my scenario. Hope it ill work there too.

Comment: I updated the Jsfiddle link so can you retry ? 

In fact you can use any element in the DOM as the dialog panel. The flow should be: 1. on event trigger --> 2. modify the dialog HTML using jQuery --> 3. show the dialog.

Comment: Dio Phung:Thank you so much. Your idea really did magic for me. It worked as per my expectation. I don't have words actually to say thanks. I was trying this since last two days. Thanks once again. Upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) ! The idea is to modify your popup HTML first, then show it later.